# Next js 13 with NextAuth - Not able to get data from an API route when user is not logged in

Tags: next-auth, next.js13

I am trying to get data to my index page without the user needs to be logged in. If the user isn't logged in the route throws the error from the catch block. If the user is logged in it works just fine. How do I exclude my route from authentication with NextAuth?

I am using "next": "13.4.3" and "next-auth": "^4.22.1",

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import testUser from '@/app/utils/models/userModel';

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    try {
        const jobPostings = await testUser.find().select('jobPostings');
        const allJobPostings = jobPostings.map((user) => user.jobPostings).flat();
        return NextResponse.json({ jobPostings: allJobPostings });
    } catch (err) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Something went wrong' }, { status: 400 });
    }
};`
```

```
`import NextAuth, { AuthOptions, SessionOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';
import userTest from '@/app/utils/models/userModel';
import connectionToDB from '@/app/utils/database';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

/* google auth */
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string;

/* github auth */
const GITHUB_ID = process.env.GITHUB_ID as string;
const GITHUB_SECRET = process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string;

/* mail magic link auth */
const EMAIL_SERVER_HOST = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST as string;
const EMAIL_SERVER_PORT = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT ? parseInt(process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT) : undefined;
const EMAIL_SERVER_USER = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER as string;
const EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD as string;


const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret: GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
       
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,

    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
            connectionToDB();

            try {
                const userEmail = user?.email;

                const userCheck = await userTest.findOne({ email: userEmail });

                if (!userCheck) {
                    await userTest.create({
                        email: userEmail,
                    });
                    console.log('User not in DB');
                } else {
                    console.log('User already in DB');
                }

                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            }
        },
    },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I am a new developer. Suggestions for improvement in regard to my post are welcome.

I tried to exclude the route from NextAuth to make it unprotected, but all suggested solutions i found didn't work with the NextAuth version i am using